# "До свиданья, наш ласковый Миша!" - Миша с прописной?

Tags: прописная

Во фразе "До свиданья, наш ласковый миша!" - из песни на закрытии Олимпиады-80 - слово "миша" с прописной или строчной?

Answer (score 3):

Медвежонок Миша (или Мишка) — талисман XXII летних Олимпийских игр, проходивших в 1980 году в Москве.
Имя Миша (Мишка, Михаил, Михаил Потапыч) — традиционное русское прозвище медведя, под которым он выступает во многих русских народных сказках.
Песня называется [**"До свиданья, Москва"**](http://www.norma40.ru/chd/bymosc.htm), автор слов — Н. Добронравов, автор музыки — А. Пахмутова, первым песню исполнил Л. Лещенко.

*На трибунах становится тише...

Тает быстрое время чудес.

**До свиданья, наш ласковый Миша,**

Возвращайся в свой сказочный лес.*

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что ответ зависит от того, является ли в данной фразе "миша" именем собственным или нарицательным для "медведя". Насколько помню, символ Олимпиады-80 был медведь по имени Миша. 
В песне мы прощались с конкретным медведем. И, скорее всего, к нему обращались по имени. То есть, с большой буквы. 
Но это можно трактовать и как прощание с медведем - символом России. Тогда он не был так "раскручен", но всё же.. И если так, то с маленькой.

Answer (score 1):

Поищите в Интернете, в Нацкорпусе — везде Миша с заглавной. В конце концов, у слов песни есть автор, и он так решил. И это логично, так как у олимпийских талисманов, как правило, было имя собственное (1972 - такса Вальдих, 1976 - бобр Амик, 1980 - медвежонок Миша, 1984 - орлёнок Сэм, 1988 - тигренок Ходори, 1992 - щенок Коби, 1996 - непонятное существо Иззи, 2000 - утконос Сид, кукабара Олли и ехидна Милли, 2004 - античные куклы Афина и Фобос и т. д.).